# readFromData:ofType:error: called before loading nib so I can't use my IBOutlets D:<

Tags: cocoa, nsview, nib

I have an application that uses NSDocument to open files. I have an NSView in my NIB, and I'd like to set it's size according to the image opened:

```
- (BOOL)readFromData:(NSData *)data ofType:(NSString *)typeName error:(NSError **)outError {
  NSLog("FOO");
  // Load image
  // ...

  // Change size
  [mainView setFrameSize:NSMakeRect(image.size.width, image.size.height)];
  [mainView display]; // Redraw

  [image release];
  return YES;
}
```

However, I did a little foobar check: 'FOO' is logged in `readFromData:ofType:error:` and 'BAR' is logged in the view's `initWithFrame:` method, but the output in the console is:

```
2010-10-30 16:20:45.670 Pwnshop[513:a0f] Foo
2010-10-30 16:20:45.680 Pwnshop[513:a0f] Bar
```

Meaning that I'm sending the `setFrameSize:` message to an uninitiated NSView.

How can I make NSDocument load the nib first, and **then** do `readFromData:ofType:error:`, or better change the view size **after** the nib is loaded?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I make NSDocument load the nib first, and then do `readFromData:ofType:error:`, …

You can't.

Edit from the year 2011: But if you can require Snow Leopard or later, you can override [the `canConcurrentlyReadDocumentsOfType:` class method](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSDocument_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSDocument/canConcurrentlyReadDocumentsOfType%3a) to return `YES`, in which case you will receive the `readFromData:ofType:error:` message on a background thread. Read the linked documentation for the relevant requirements and caveats.

> … or better change the view size after the nib is loaded?

Implement `windowControllerDidLoadNib:` and make your window/view changes there. Don't forget to call up to `super`, as demonstrated by the implementation provided by the NSDocument-subclass template.